# SQL Statement with a simple join

Tags: sql

I have problems to do a SQL statement. I have the following example-tables:

Table 1:

```
ID - | - Name
1; ABC
2; DEF
3; GHI
```

Table 2:

```
ID - | - Bool
1; true
1; false
2; true
3; false
3; false
```

I want to join the tables but show only the entities, which have NO false in table 2. Example:
Is there a false and a true in one entity, I don't want to have the Entity in my Result. Are there true true in one entity, it is ok.
My Problem are Entitys, which have true and false in table 2...
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Since your IDs have duplicates in table2, you'll have to do some inventory/counting:

```
SELECT table1.ID, table1.Name,
    SUM(table2.Bool = false) as trues,
    SUM(table1.Bool = true) as falses
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
GROUP BY table1.ID
HAVING falses = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all records that have a TRUE record in Table 2 but no FALSE record:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT NULL
   FROM Table2 t2
   WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
   AND t2.Bool = 'true'
) 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT NULL
   FROM Table2 t2
   WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
   AND t2.Bool = 'false'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a DB handy, but I wonder if this would work:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id not in (select id from table2 where Bool = 'false')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column 'bool' on table 2 is truly the `boolean` data type, which is 1 if true, and 0 if false, then any ID having a minimum bool value not equal to 0 must have no false values.

So you could run: (see **fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76639/1/0)

```
select t1.id, t1.name
  from table_1 t1
  join (select id from table_2 group by id having min(bool) <> 0) v
    on t1.id = v.id
```